# conformal mapping of a curved channel to a rectangular domain

Tags: complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I need to find a transformation function that maps either one of the curved domains on the left of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0shg8.png) (Green) to a rectangular domain (Blue domain on the right).
My background is not math and I have been studying much about conformal mapping lately, but I could not find a clue.
Please have a look at the picture.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: What is the middle bounding curve on the top of the green region?

Comment: That is supposed to be one side of an airfoil. I can produce a polynomial function for that curved portion.

Comment: @Ali: Welcome to Math.SE! There's no general way to give an analytic formula for such a mapping, even with an exact description of the green regions (which the figure does not provide). Could you please say a little about why (for what purpose) you need this mapping?

Comment: Sure Andrew,
I want to solve the fluid flow around an airfoil and I would like my solver to solve a transport equation for a particular scalar as well.
The source, dissipation and diffusion terms in the transport equation of the scalar could be given for a curvilinear coordinate system. I need to transform them and re-write them for cartesian coordiante system so that it could be easily implemented in the solver.
I hope that paints a better picture of the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I found an article here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999183900207
But have many questions. Is there anyone that fully understands this article and can help me implement it in my study?

Comment: Hi again,
Any kind of help is much appreciated. The article I mentioned is trying to do pretty much what I intend to do but I have problems understanding some parts of it.